# What is this port on my laptop?

Tags: port

Next to my headphone and microphone 3.5mm jacks there is one more 3.5mm port with a little image that looks like the image below.

What is this port? What can it be used for?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a [mini-TOSLINK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOSLINK#Mini-TOSLINK) port. You'll need a cable like the one below to hook it up.

You can use it for hooking your laptop up to a home theater or other stereo with a plug for optical connections.

[image: mini-TOSLINK]

Comment: [mini-toslink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOSLINK#Mini-TOSLINK) - @Melikoth: I added an image to your answer - please delete it if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks. Can I use this port to output to CRT type TV (the old type of TV's) ?

Comment: @Jacques, no... This is digital. Your old CRT TV is analog.

Comment: Is there a way to output Video + Audio to a CRT TV and what would be the easiest way? My laptop is modern and has all the modern ports but my TV not so modern.. Thanks.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Thanks for adding the picture, I couldn't find one of exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Jacques: Not directly with modern laptops. Some old ones had an Composite or S-video connectors, but most new ones come with an HDMI interface which can pass both video and audio signals. The highest quality solution would be to find a newer model TV on the cheap that has the plugs you need, making your current one work with the laptop will likely be a mess of parts.